# Advanced tab missing in Network Adapter properties after installing 28.2 version of Network Adapter Driver

Tags: windows, networking, windows-server-2012-r2, intel

I recently updated my **Intel X540-AT2 Network Card** on a **Windows Server 2012 R2** system to the **latest version 28.2**. This update included both the driver package and the Intel® PROSet package, which I downloaded from the official Intel website.

However, I have noticed that the "**Advanced"** tab in the **Network Adapter properties** is ***no longer visible*** after this update. This "Advanced" tab was previously where I accessed various advanced settings and configurations for my network adapter.

Is anyone else experiencing this issue, or does anyone have insight into why the "Advanced" tab might be missing with this update?
Any help or suggestions on how to access these advanced settings or restore the missing tab would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your assistance!